# How can i randomly sample from a distribution already fitted with allfitdist in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random, data-fitting

I 've found the best fitting of a variable distribution (D(:,2)) using the function "allfitdist". Now i want to save this result in a structure and then i want to randomly sample 10000 times from this result.  I'm using this code:

```
[Ddg2 PDdg2] = allfitdist(D(:,2),'cdf')
My(2).result = PDdg2{1,1} %generalized pareto
output = random(My(2).result,10000)
```

Something is weard because in the output i get a really big matrix.  Maybe i'm wrong in the third raw of the code, when i randomly sample from this distribution.
Someone can help me?

Comment: What size of `output` were you expecting? Please provide a sample of `D(:,2)` so we may run your code to see your problem. What is `allfitdist`? It does not come with MATLAB. If your problem is not related to `allfitdist` and you're getting expected output from  `allfitdist`. Then you need to provide what `My(2).result`  is and what your expected output from `random` is. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: is possible to attach file? i don't see it... i would like to attach the function allfitdist and the matrix...

Comment: If your output from `allfitdist` is what you're expecting from it then we do not need that file. We only need an MCVE of the problematic part. And no, files cannot be attached. If it is an open-source small script, add it simply as code and add reference/credits to the original source. If it is long file or a toolbox, link to that toolbox will be sufficient.

Comment: ok. From allfidst i receive this:                                                                        
ans = 

  GeneralizedExtremeValueDistribution

  Generalized Extreme Value distribution
        k = 0.914206   [0.699899, 1.12851]
    sigma =  49.5972   [40.5799, 60.6181]
       mu =  169.966   [161.716, 178.217]                                                                      now i want to sample from this distribution but i need a matrix of 1 column and 10000 rows.. i got a matrix of 10000 rows and 10000 columns. I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of `random`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html#d120e623701) says:

> `R = random(___,sz1,...,szN)` or `R = random(___,[sz1,...,szN])` generates a `sz1`-by-⋯-by-`szN` array of random numbers from the specified probability distribution using input arguments...
>   ...
>   If you specify a single value `sz1`, then `R` is a square matrix of size `sz1`.

You have specified `sz1` as `10000` which is a single value and hence your `output` matrix is `10000×10000`.

So the solution is:

```
output = random(pd,1,10000);
```